# error handler in Password Manager stops button from Functioning

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, passwords

In my Visual Basic Password Manager app, i have the option of generating a random 8 string length of integers.Which works fine.

The other option is to let the user Inputbox() each 2 digit integer into 4 seperate variables and then join them all together as  the variable "Final Input"

This was all working fine until i started programming in the error handlers to let users only input 2 character long NUMERIC values. This resulted in my "Manual input" option button not activating the input boxes to start taking in numbers.

Any help with the code will be heavily appreciated

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim number1 As Integer = 0
    Dim number2 As Integer = 0
    Dim number3 As Integer = 0
    Dim number4 As Integer = 0
    Dim finalinput As String
    Dim finalgenerated As New Random
    Dim rn1 As New Random
    Dim rn2 As New Random
    Dim rn3 As New Random
    Dim rn4 As New Random
    'asks for sections of final number

    While TextBox1.Text.Length <> 2 And IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) = True
        TextBox1.Text = InputBox("Please enter first 2 integer number")
        number1 = TextBox1.Text
        MsgBox("number 1 added")
    End While

    While TextBox2.Text.Length <> 2 And IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) = True
        TextBox2.Text = InputBox("Please enter second 2 integer number")
        number2 = TextBox2.Text
        MsgBox("number 2 added")
    End While

    While TextBox3.Text.Length <> 2 And IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) = True
        TextBox3.Text = InputBox("Please enter third 2 integer number")
        number3 = TextBox3.Text
        MsgBox("number 3 added")
    End While

    While TextBox4.Text.Length <> 2 And IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) = True
        TextBox4.Text = InputBox("Please enter fourth 2 integer number")
        number4 = TextBox4.Text
        MsgBox("number 4 added")
    End While
    finalinput = CStr(number1) + CStr(number2) + CStr(number3) + CStr(number4)
    savedcode = finalinput
```

Comment: I dont know how to fix `not working at all` because that doesnt tell me anything at all.  But for sure, you do not need 5 individual Random objects.  For certain the ONE you do need should be form level, not local to a click event

Comment: edited- by "not working at all" i meant no longer bringing up input boxes to take in integers.

Comment: Could it be the IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) = True is not firing because there's nothing in the textbox when you start?

Comment: I thought you had it! but no it's not it